# How to Run a Loop through multiple groups in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data set with multiple variables, where I want to sum the value of two columns by row. If the sum is below a set threshold, I want to replace the values of the second column (that is being summed) with the sum value. However, I want to do this by group.

My dataframe is setup with 18 different columns, these include "Closed_Grid", "Closed_Sets", "BestAvail", "Best_Sets" and "Best_Distance".  "BestAvail", "Best_Sets" and "Best_Distance" are repeated for 2nd Best, 3rd, 4th and 5th. I am using this information to determine a final Destination Location (column 18 "Dest_Grid") which will be filled with a grid index from "BestAvail", "2nd_Best", etc. based on the conditional summing of the "Closed_Sets" and Destination Sets (Best, 2nd, etc..). In the end, if the sum of the two columns in <=150, that grid cell ("BestAvail") will be the "Dest_Grid". If the sum is >150 then it will move on to the next block and calculate the new sum between "Closed_Sets" and "2nd_Best" and so on until all "Closed_Sets" have a "Dest_Grid".

So just to help simplify this for the sake of what I am trying to accomplish, a sample (and subset) of my dataset looks like this:

```
Closed_Grid Closed_Sets BestAvail Best_Sets
GY38         72.875     GX38       91.75
GY37         87.125     GX38       91.75
GY36         39.875     GX38       91.75
GZ38         29         GX38       91.75
GZ37         80         GX38       91.75
GY35         2.375      GX38       91.75
GZ36         125.25     GX38       91.75
GZ35         29.875     GX38       91.75
GY39         17.5       GX39       54.125
HA35         34.375     GZ33       30.5
GZ41         109.625    GZ42       76.76
GY41         82.28571   GZ42       76.75
HA41         87.5       GZ42       76.75
GZ40         104.75     GZ42       76.75
GY40         60.625     GZ42       76.75
HA40         79.875     GZ42       76.75
GZ39         51.57143   GZ42       76.75
HA39         71         GZ42       76.75
```

I have first arranged my data by "BestAvail" and by "Distance" (smallest to largest) using:

```
Destination <- Destination %>% arrange(BestAvail, BestDistance)
```

This is an important order as the Closed_Grid with the smallest distance to BestAvail get first priority to move into that grid.

So now I want to Sum "Closed_Sets" and "Best_Sets" by row, within a group (i.e. where "BestAvail" is the same). Whenever the sum of a row is less than a threshold (150), the "Best_Sets" value is replaced with the prior sum. So, what I want the output to be is this:

```
Closed_Grid Closed_Sets BestAvail Best_Sets BestSum
GY38         72.875     GX38       91.75    164.6250
GY37         87.125     GX38       91.75    178.8750
GY36         39.875     GX38       91.75    131.625
GZ38         29         GX38       131.625  160.625  
GZ37         80         GX38       131.625  211.625
GY35         2.375      GX38       131.625  134.00
GZ36         125.25     GX38       134.00   259.250
GZ35         29.875     GX38       134.00   163.8750
GY39         17.5       GX39       54.125   71.625
HA35         34.375     GZ33       30.5     64.875
GZ41         109.625    GZ42       76.75    186.375
GY41         82.28571   GZ42       76.75    159.03571
HA41         87.5       GZ42       76.75    164.25
GZ40         104.75     GZ42       76.75    181.5
GY40         60.625     GZ42       76.75    137.375
HA40         79.875     GZ42       137.375  217.25
GZ39         51.57143   GZ42       137.375  188.94643
HA39         71         GZ42       137.375  208.375
```

I can partially achieve this by using this loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Destination)){
    Destination$BestSum[i] <- sum(Destination$Closed_Sets[i], Destination$Best_Sets[i])
    if (Destination$BestSum[i] <= 150){
      Destination [i:length(Destination),"Best_Sets"] <- Destination$BestSum[i]
    }
  }
```

However, this code makes all of the "Best_Sets" a value of 134, and doesn't restart when the "BestAvail" value changes, which in turns messes up all of the following sums. Ultimately, I am trying to do a conditional cumulative sum of every "Closed_Set" in a group that remains under a value of 150.

This is part of a model I am working on that will have upwards of 150+ individual datasets run through it, all with varying lengths and values. This particular bit of code will also need to iterate through the 2nd, 3rd, etc. sets so it needs to be something that can be repeated and the variables easily changed.

I have tried using the unique() function in the loop, tried making my own function to use in dplyr (this would be ideal!), tried different cumulative sums with reset functions,and have searched through hundreds of threads at this point.

I am relatively new to R and programming and am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I have looked through multiple discussions on every possible question relating to this but can't seem to get it to work on my data.

I hope what I am trying to achieve makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried the couple of solutions offered, but unfortunately I couldn't get them to really work for me. However, I did come up with a solution (with the help of my supervisor), it is super ugly and long but it worked to give me my wanted outcome.

```
##Rearrange data from ascending order of Best Avail grids and Distance
Destination <- Destination %>% arrange(BestAvail, BestDistance)

####Set Levels and change to a factor in order to iterate through the different groups
Destination$Closed_Grid <- droplevels(Destination$Closed_Grid)
Destination$BestAvail <- as.factor(Destination$BestAvail)

###create a working file
WorkingDest = Destination[FALSE,]

##Loop that conditionally sums row by group, gives final dest grid, and pastes into working file
for (f in 1: nlevels (Destination$BestAvail)) {
  work <- subset(Destination, BestAvail == levels(Destination$BestAvail)[f])
  for (i in 1:nrow(work)){
    for (j in 1:length(levels(work$BestAvail))){
      if (as.character(work$BestAvail)[i] == as.character(levels(work$BestAvail)[j])){
        work$BestSum[i] <- sum(work$Closed_Sets[i], work$Best_Sets[i])
        if (work$BestSum[i] <= 150){
          work [i:nrow(work),"Best_Sets"] <- work$BestSum[i]
          work$Dest_Grid [i] <- as.character(work$BestAvail)[i]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  WorkingDest <- rbind(WorkingDest, work)
}
###Create Results DataFrame for Closed Sets that have Moved
FinalDestination <- WorkingDest[WorkingDest$Dest_Grid != 0,]

##Create a working df that only have the new base sets for matching purposes
MaxSetsBest <- WorkingDest %>%
  group_by(BestAvail) %>% top_n(1, Best_Sets)
MaxSetsBest <- MaxSetsBest[!duplicated(MaxSetsBest$BestAvail), ]

####change basesets for SecondBest based on previous iterations
for(id in 1:nrow(MaxSetsBest)){
  WorkingDest$Second_Sets[WorkingDest$SecondBest %in% MaxSetsBest$BestAvail[id]] <- MaxSetsBest$Best_Sets[id]
}
rm(id)

##Reset Destination with new basesets
Destination <- WorkingDest

##Remove Closed Grids that have moved from working file
Destination <- WorkingDest[!WorkingDest$Dest_Grid != 0,]
```

I then reran the same code for the SecondBest options, and so on. I know it's not nice coding, but it works, and I have very small dataframes (max 50 rows) being run through this so speed isn't a huge factor. If anyone knows a way to make this nicer great, but if not it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Note: the following R code is not very idiomatic and will likely be very slow. I don't recommend you use this style for common tasks.

```
# build the data frame
Closed_Grid = c(
  "GY38",
  "GY37",
  "GY36",
  "GZ38",
  "GZ37",
  "GY35",
  "GZ36",
  "GZ35",
  "GY39",
  "HA35",
  "GZ41",
  "GY41",
  "HA41",
  "GZ40",
  "GY40",
  "HA40",
  "GZ39",
  "HA39"
)

Closed_Sets = c(
  72.875,
  87.125,
  39.875,
  29,
  80,
  2.375,
  125.25,
  29.875,
  17.5,
  34.375,
  109.625,
  82.28571,
  87.5,
  104.75,
  60.625,
  79.875,
  51.57143,
  71
)

BestAvail = c(
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX38",
  "GX39",
  "GZ33",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42",
  "GZ42"
)

Best_Sets = c(
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  91.75,
  54.125,
  30.5,
  76.76,
  76.75,
  76.75,
  76.75,
  76.75,
  76.75,
  76.75,
  76.75
)

dat <- data.frame(
  Closed_Grid, Closed_Sets, BestAvail, Best_Sets,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# allocate a vector; this makes the for() loop use significantly
# less memory, see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#avoid-copies

dat$BestSum <- NA_real_

# split the data frame to work on one group of BestAvail at a time
Destination <- split(dat, factor(dat[["BestAvail"]]))

Destination <- lapply(Destination, function(dat) {
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {

    BestSum <- rowSums(dat[i, c("Closed_Sets", "Best_Sets")])
    dat[i, "BestSum"] <- BestSum

    if (as.integer(i) > 1L) {
      if (BestSum < 150.0) {
        dat[i+1:(nrow(dat) - i), "Best_Sets"] <- dat[i, "BestSum"]
      }
    }

  }

  dat

})

# recombine
Destination <- do.call(rbind, Destination)

Destination
```

This code is likely going to be very slow. If you're running this on large data sets it might be worth writing this in c++.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I guess I should have mentioned that I have also ordered the rows based on Distance (another column that I didn't include in my example) and by BestAvail. I also have more columns (2ndBest, 3rd Best and so on) and I plan on  running this same conditional sum for each of those blocks as well. It will also be automated to run through 150+ dataframes so I'm not sure this will work for what I'm trying to do. I can give it a go just to try though. Thanks again!

Comment: Ideally, yes, you would have specified that up front. As it stands this answers your question and you should be able to adapt your code to run on other data sets/variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Destination is your dataframe

Try this:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  Destination %>%
   arrange(BestAvail, BestDistance) %>%
   mutate(BestSum = Closed_Sets + Best_Sets) %>%
   group_by(BestAvail) %>%
   mutate(Best_Sets2 = case_when(BestSum < 150 ~ lag(BestSum),
                                 TRUE ~ Best_Sets))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion - unfortunately it isn't working for me. It's giving me the wrong sums and some NAs in the Best_Sets2 but not sure where it's going wrong.